# Unit Testing CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, unit-testing

We have two CodeIgniter instances in production which I've just finished migrating to CodeIgniter 3. A large gap has been left in our code base since it was not designed with testability in mind. As the applications have evolved over 4 years throwing a test harness around it is not so simple.

There is code in controllers that just render views and code in views that just post to controllers and getting between the two is maddening.

I've tried to use **PHPUnit** to achieve testing as well as the CodeIgniter Unit Test class, but I always wind up back at this conundrum. Is there any advice people in similar situations can offer?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's quite hard to achieve testing in a legacy application in Codeigniter... What I ended up doing is:

- Libraries and classes that can be isolated, are tested via PHPUnit
- Controllers and rendering are tested via BDD. I use Codeception and Selenium (with Mozilla browser) to perform Acceptance tests, that at least makes sure that all is working alright (rendering, placing of elements and so on).

I would also like hearing from others experience. I personally use Codeception all the time even for Unit test (at the end, is built over PHPUnit). Main page: http://codeception.com/

Comment: Codeinception seems pretty awesome!

Admittedly I'm not as far along as you, but I saw myself trending that way. "BDD" - I didn't even know it was formally termed anything. Usually I end up var dumping to the log and seeing what's there lol. Our PHP codebase is such wild west development, you can only laugh. Else you'll cry.

Comment: Well, it's a way full of pain, but take it easy and you'll end up with something you can manage, ;D